# Aligning all the six authors information in IEEE format

Tags: ieeetran, ieeeconf

I am trying to write all the six author and their respective information but I am facing two problems.

1. I cant align the first author info with 4th, 2nd with 5th and so on.
2. The last two departments, College of Computing &  Applied Sciences are too much close to one another

[image: Here is the image]

Here is my code

```
\author{\IEEEauthorblockN{First Author Name}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{Department of CSE} \\ 
\textit{Some University, Some Country}\\
City, Country \\
Email}
\and
\IEEEauthorblockN{Second Author Name}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{Department of CSE} \\
\textit{Some University, Some Country}\\
City, Country \\
Email}
\and
\IEEEauthorblockN{Third Author Name}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{Department of CSE} \\
\textit{Some University, Some Country}\\
City, Country \\
Email}
\linebreakand % <------------- \and with a line-break
\and
\IEEEauthorblockN{4th Author Name}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{Department of CSE} \\
\textit{Some University, Some Country}\\
City, Country \\
Email}
\and
\IEEEauthorblockN{Fifth Author Name}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{College of Computing \& Applied Sciences}\\ \vspace{0.01cm}
\textit{Universiti Malaysia Pahang}\\
Pekan, Malaysia \\
Email}
\and
\IEEEauthorblockN{Sixth Author Name}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{College of Computing \& Applied Sciences}\\ \vspace{0.01
cm}
\textit{Universiti Malaysia Pahang}\\
Pekan, Malaysia \\
Emai}
}
```

How can I fix these to make this look good? I have tried almost everything I found but it does nothing but mess it up a little bit more.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please edit your posting to show the code that gives rise to the screenshot shown above.

Comment: @Mico Sorry I forgot to do that. Edited

Comment: By "IEEE format", do you mean the `IEEEtran` document class?

Answer (score 2):

As shown in `"C:\texlive\2023\texmf-dist\doc\latex\ieeetran\bare_conf.tex"`:

```latex
% author names and affiliations
% use a multiple column layout for up to three different
% affiliations
\author{\IEEEauthorblockN{Michael Shell}
\IEEEauthorblockA{School of Electrical and\\Computer Engineering\\
Georgia Institute of Technology\\
Atlanta, Georgia 30332--0250\\
Email: http://www.michaelshell.org/contact.html}
\and
\IEEEauthorblockN{Homer Simpson}
\IEEEauthorblockA{Twentieth Century Fox\\
Springfield, USA\\
Email: homer@thesimpsons.com}
\and
\IEEEauthorblockN{James Kirk\\ and Montgomery Scott}
\IEEEauthorblockA{Starfleet Academy\\
San Francisco, California 96678--2391\\
Telephone: (800) 555--1212\\
Fax: (888) 555--1212}}


% for over three affiliations, or if they all won't fit within the width
% of the page, use this alternative format:
% 
%\author{\IEEEauthorblockN{Michael Shell\IEEEauthorrefmark{1},
%Homer Simpson\IEEEauthorrefmark{2},
%James Kirk\IEEEauthorrefmark{3}, 
%Montgomery Scott\IEEEauthorrefmark{3} and
%Eldon Tyrell\IEEEauthorrefmark{4}}
%\IEEEauthorblockA{\IEEEauthorrefmark{1}School of Electrical and Computer Engineering\\
%Georgia Institute of Technology,
%Atlanta, Georgia 30332--0250\\ Email: see http://www.michaelshell.org/contact.html}
%\IEEEauthorblockA{\IEEEauthorrefmark{2}Twentieth Century Fox, Springfield, USA\\
%Email: homer@thesimpsons.com}
%\IEEEauthorblockA{\IEEEauthorrefmark{3}Starfleet Academy, San Francisco, California 96678-2391\\
%Telephone: (800) 555--1212, Fax: (888) 555--1212}
%\IEEEauthorblockA{\IEEEauthorrefmark{4}Tyrell Inc., 123 Replicant Street, Los Angeles, California 90210--4321}}
```

> author names and affiliations use a multiple column layout for **up to three** different affiliations
> for **over three** affiliations, or if they all won't fit within the width of the page, use this alternative format

In your demo, the column is larger than three. You should use alternative format.

```latex
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\begin{document}
\title{title}
\author{\IEEEauthorblockN{Michael Shell\IEEEauthorrefmark{1},
Homer Simpson\IEEEauthorrefmark{2},
James Kirk\IEEEauthorrefmark{3},
Montgomery Scott\IEEEauthorrefmark{3} and
Eldon Tyrell\IEEEauthorrefmark{4}}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\IEEEauthorrefmark{1}School of Electrical and Computer Engineering\\
Georgia Institute of Technology,
Atlanta, Georgia 30332--0250\\ Email: see http://www.michaelshell.org/contact.html}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\IEEEauthorrefmark{2}Twentieth Century Fox, Springfield, USA\\
Email: homer@thesimpsons.com}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\IEEEauthorrefmark{3}Starfleet Academy, San Francisco, California 96678-2391\\
Telephone: (800) 555--1212, Fax: (888) 555--1212}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\IEEEauthorrefmark{4}Tyrell Inc., 123 Replicant Street, Los Angeles, California 90210--4321}}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image]