# IEEEtran document class — how to align 10 authors properly

Tags: ieeetran, author, ieee-style

I am writing a paper and want to format the authors section for 10 authors. Using the basic IEEE template (see code below), I managed to have this (see Picture). Can someone know how this can be more organized: 5 authors on 1st line, 5 authors on the second line?

```
\author{\IEEEauthorblockN{1\textsuperscript{st} Given Name Surname}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{dept. name of organization (of Aff.)} \\
\textit{name of organization (of Aff.)}\\
City, Country \\
email address or ORCID}
\and
\IEEEauthorblockN{2\textsuperscript{nd} Given Name Surname}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{dept. name of organization (of Aff.)} \\
\textit{name of organization (of Aff.)}\\
City, Country \\
email address or ORCID}
\and
\IEEEauthorblockN{3\textsuperscript{rd} Given Name Surname}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{dept. name of organization (of Aff.)} \\
\textit{name of organization (of Aff.)}\\
City, Country \\
email address or ORCID}
\and
\IEEEauthorblockN{4\textsuperscript{th} Given Name Surname}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{dept. name of organization (of Aff.)} \\
\textit{name of organization (of Aff.)}\\
City, Country \\
email address or ORCID}
\and
\IEEEauthorblockN{5\textsuperscript{th} Given Name Surname}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{dept. name of organization (of Aff.)} \\
\textit{name of organization (of Aff.)}\\
City, Country \\
email address or ORCID}
\and
\IEEEauthorblockN{6\textsuperscript{th} Given Name Surname}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{dept. name of organization (of Aff.)} \\
\textit{name of organization (of Aff.)}\\
City, Country \\
email address or ORCID}
\and
\IEEEauthorblockN{7\textsuperscript{th} Given Name Surname}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{dept. name of organization (of Aff.)} \\
\textit{name of organization (of Aff.)}\\
City, Country \\
email address or ORCID}
\and
\IEEEauthorblockN{8\textsuperscript{th} Given Name Surname}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{dept. name of organization (of Aff.)} \\
\textit{name of organization (of Aff.)}\\
City, Country \\
email address or ORCID}
\and
\IEEEauthorblockN{9\textsuperscript{th} Given Name Surname}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{dept. name of organization (of Aff.)} \\
\textit{name of organization (of Aff.)}\\
City, Country \\
email address or ORCID}
\and
\IEEEauthorblockN{10\textsuperscript{th} Given Name Surname}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{dept. name of organization (of Aff.)} \\
\textit{name of organization (of Aff.)}\\
City, Country \\
email address or ORCID}
}
```

[image]

Comment: As mentioned in my answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/681370/238422, you should use another format.